# Realm java distinct RealmQuery

Tags: java, android, distinct, realm

```
class Item {
    int type;
    String value;
}

RealmResults<Item> result = realm.where(Item.class)
        .equalTo("type", type)
        .findAll();
```

There are a lot of duplicated values on Realm.
I wanted to get unique value result.

```
RealmResults<Item> result = realm.where(Item.class)
        .equalTo("type", type)
        .distinct("value")
        .findAll();
```

like this.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: No. Your solution is the only true.